# wp_lostpassword_url not escaped

Tags: login, password

I have ajax login form, and a lost password link that gets it's url with `wp_lostpassword_url()` function.

When I validate the page I get

`Error: & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &amp;.)`

On line where that link is. Can that be fixed somehow?

I have woocommerce active so it sends me to woocommerce page for login.

I could create a custom function that will send user to default forgotten password page

`mysite.com/theme/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword`

But that would be a last resort solution.

EDIT:

https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=wc_lostpassword_url

The function has to be escaped properly with `esc_url()`.

Comment: Is this a woocommerce issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please post the line of code that uses `wp_lostpassword_url()`

(Can't comment not enough rep :()

Comment: It's just `<a class="lost" href="<?php echo wp_lostpassword_url(); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e('Lost your password?','theme') ?></a>`

Comment: Can you try <a class="lost" href="<?php echo urlencode(wp_lostpassword_url()); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e('Lost your password?','theme') ?></a>

Comment: `urlencode` messed up my url, but apparently `esc_url()` fixed the issue :) Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: No problem. Wonder what the issue is. I know WooCommerce pages do parse code differently such as line breaks etc.

Comment: It turns out that it's just how it should go: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=wc_lostpassword_url

Comment: Thank you Pete, as you can see I do not have enough rep to comment, but still had a desire to help this individual.  What shall I do with this "answer"?